# How can I change the padding of a button in extjs?

Tags: extjs

Is it possible to change the padding of a button that is placed inside a FormPanel dynamically?

Thanks,
Y_Y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSS to change the padding

```
Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: 'Click me',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    cls: 'my-btn'
});

/* The button wrapper */
.my-btn.x-btn {
   padding: 5px;
}

 /** or the button itself */
.my-btn.x-btn button {...}
```

Or you can hack it with JS

```
Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: 'Click me',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    padding: 10,
    handler: function() {
        alert('You clicked the button!');
    }
});
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: can a custom css class be applied to any component?

Comment: @Christoph Yes. See  http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-cls